# Ajax - Check if article exist in database and change button attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have two forms which consists of two hidden input fields that are holding some values like idUser and idCampaign.

```
{!! Form::open(['class' => 'ajax-form']) !!}
    <input type="hidden" name = "idUser" id="idUser" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}">
    <input type="hidden" name = "idCampaign" id="idCampaign" value="{{$docinfo['attrs']['sid']}}">
    <button type="submit" id="test"><img align="right" src="{{ asset('/img/icon_add_fav.png')}}"></button>

{!! Form::close() !!}

{!! Form::open(['class' => 'ajax-form2']) !!}
    <input type="hidden" name = "idUser" id="idUser" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}">
    <input type="hidden" name = "idCampaign" id="idCampaign" value="{{$docinfo['attrs']['sid']}}">
    <button type="submit" id="test2" style="display: none;">Delete</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Then, I created two ajax calls for each form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".ajax-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $("#test").hide();
    $("#test2").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{ url('addFavorites') }}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            swal("Success!", "You added the campaign "+ data.idCampaign + " to favorites!", "success")
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Error")
        },
        complete: function (data) {
      $("#test").hide();
     }
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".ajax-form2").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $("#test2").hide();
    $("#test").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{ url('deleteFavorites') }}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            swal("Success!", "You deleted the campaign to favorites! " + data.idCampaign, "success")
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Error")
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

It works fine with adding and deleting items into the db. After adding, the button changes to Delete. But problem occurs when I reload the page. The forms (button) for adding are shown again. Is there a way to check on page load if the data is in db, and show appropriate form. If the data is not in db, show form for deleting `(ajax-form2)`. Otherwise, show form for inserting `(ajax-form)`. Btw. `addFavorites` and `deleteFavorites` are in controller.

Comment: jquery uses $(window).load to this, is called after html is done and css is done, so you can do here if you want to done by javascript, but could be better done in php template drawn

Comment: I tried to check in Controller, but don't know how to pass this `idCampaign` value. For `idUser` it can be done easily with `Auth::user()->id`

Comment: in the tpl, will make a filter to draw it one each and not both?

Comment: You are passing `$docinfo` in this template so obviously it would be available in your controller, otherwise how is this variable available?

Comment: I'm using Sphinx search in SearchController to get results. In that case I'd need to loop through all results (which could be a few thousands) to get the wanted id and then compare it with records where favorites are stored. Is there a better and more efficient way to do this?